# Почему вызов boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ мьютекс }, не даёт выполняться следующим за ним строкам кода?

Tags: c++, boost, mutex, inter-process

Пишу на C++ в Visual Studio 2019 Community приложение межпроцессного взаимодействия с использованием boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory. Процесс-сервер представляет собой консольное приложение C++, а процесс-клиент - оконное приложение Win32 API. Проекты обоих приложений находятся в одном решении и оба являются запускаемыми проектами. Порядок сборки - сначала сервер, а потом - клиент и запускаются они в том же порядке. Код взаимодействия процессов выполняется в соответствующей задаче PPL, как на клиенте, так и на сервере. для синхронизации работы клиента и сервера использую boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex. У меня следующий вопрос: почему, когда я, в пошаговой отладке, дохожу до строки кода

```
scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mtx };
```

(где mtx это указатель на interprocess_mutex) на процессе-сервере либо на процессе-клиенте и в очередной раз нажимаю F10 для выполнения очередного шага, то переход к следующей строке отлаживаемого кода не выполняется, хотя окно приложения, при этом, не зависает. (В окне приложения Win32, являющегося клиентом доступны кнопки.) Но, если я в приложении-клиенте Win32,например, попытаюсь выполнить отмену задачи взаимодействия с сервером, то приложение зависает на строке

```
operatingSupportTask.wait();
```

Ниже приводится снипет кода, реализующего отмену задачи взаимодействия с сервером:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   case WM_COMMAND:
   {
       int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
       switch (wmId)
       {
          . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
          case BTN_CANCEL_SEND_FILE:
          {
             // Отменить передачу файла на сервер.
             cancelTokenSource.cancel();
             // Ожидать завершения задачи оперативной поддержки работы клиента
             // после отмены задачи отправки файла на сервер.
             operatingSupportTask.wait(); // !!! ЗДЕСЬ ЗАВИСАЕТ !!!
             . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
          }
          break;
          . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
       }
   }
   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
}
```

где: cancelTokenSource это источник токенов для отмены задачи взаимодействия с сервером, а operatingSupportTask это задача, внутри которой из источника токенов создаётся токен отмены и запускается сама задача взаимодействия с сервером, которой передаётся токен отмены. См. снипет кода взаимодействия клиента с сервером ниже.

Процесс-Клиент; снипет кода для взаимодействия клиента с сервером:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   case WM_COMMAND:
   {
       int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
       switch (wmId)
       {
          . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
          case BTN_SEND_FILE:
          {
                . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                // Отправка файла на сервер.
                operatingSupportTask = create_task([]() {
                // Создать токен отмены для задачи отправки файла на сервер.
                cancelTokenSource = cancellation_token_source();
                cancellation_token token = cancelTokenSource.get_token();
                // Создать и запустить задачу отправки файла на сервер.
                fileSendingTask = create_task([&token]()
                    {
                        // Проверить, была ли отмена задачи.
                        if (token.is_canceled())
                        {
                            cancel_current_task();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                                // Получить доступ к области общей памяти (shared memory).
                                managed_shared_memory managed_shm{ open_only, "MySharedMemory" };
                                // Получить мьютекс
                                pair<interprocess_mutex*, size_t> mutexPare = managed_shm.find<interprocess_mutex>("mtx");
                                // Получить условие запуска сервера для обработки данных клиента.
                                pair<interprocess_condition*, size_t> condExecPare = managed_shm.find< interprocess_condition>("cond_exec");
                                // Получить условие, извещения клиента о том, что полученные от него данные обработаны и ответ для него готов.
                                pair<interprocess_condition*, size_t> condDonePare = managed_shm.find< interprocess_condition>("cond_done");
                                pair<bool*, size_t> fileTransFlagPair = managed_shm.find<bool>("fileTransferInProgress");

                                // Захватить область общей памяти для выполнения передачи файла в неё.
                                scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mutexPare.first }; // !!!!
                                // Показать, что выполняется передача файла.
                                *fileTransFlagPair.first = true;
                                // Здесь - непосредственно передача файла в общую память (пока не реализовано).
                                do
                                {
                                    if (token.is_canceled())
                                    {
                                        cancel_current_task();
                                    }
                                } while (true);
                                // По окончанию передачи, уведомить сервер о том, что выполнена передача файла в общую память.
                                condExecPare.first->notify_one();
                                // Ожидать от сервера подтверждения того, что передача файла выполнилась.
                                condDonePare.first->wait(lock);
                                // Показать, что передача завершена.
                                *fileTransFlagPair.first = false;
                            }
                            catch (interprocess_exception& ex)
                            {
                                . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                            }
                        }
                    }, token);
                // Ожидать окончания задачи передачи файлов.
                fileSendingTask.wait();
                });              
             . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
          }
          break;
          . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
       }
   }
   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
}
```

Ниже приводится снипет кода для взаимодействия сервера с клиентом. Этот код находится внутри функции main() консольного приложения C++, которое является процессом-сервером.

Процесс-Сервер; снипет кода для взаимодействия с клиентом:

```
cancelTokenSource = cancellation_token_source();
cancellation_token token = cancelTokenSource.get_token();
serverTask = create_task([&token]()
    {
        // Проверить, была ли отмена задачи.
        if (token.is_canceled())
        {
            cancel_current_task();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Длина создаваемой области общей памяти.
                const int shmLength = 262144;
                // Создать область общей памяти.
                managed_shared_memory managed_shm{ open_or_create, "MySharedMemory", shmLength };
                // Определить:
                // мьютекс для синхронизации,
                interprocess_mutex* mtx = managed_shm.find_or_construct<interprocess_mutex>("mtx")();
                // флаг, показывающий, что клиент выполняет передачу файла в общую память,
                bool* fileTransferInProgress = managed_shm.find_or_construct<bool>("fileTransferInProgress")(false);
                // условие уведомления сервера о том, что клиент завершил передачу файла в общую память,
                interprocess_condition* cond_exec = managed_shm.find_or_construct<interprocess_condition>("cond_exec")();
                // условие, уведомления клиента о том, что сервер подтвердил получение файла, переданного в общую память.
                interprocess_condition* cond_done = managed_shm.find_or_construct<interprocess_condition>("cond_done")();

                scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mtx }; // !!!!
                while (1)
                {
                    // Проверить, была ли отмена задачи.
                    if (token.is_canceled())
                    {
                        cancel_current_task();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Если выполняется передача файла (пока не реализовано)
                        if (fileTransferInProgress && *fileTransferInProgress)
                        {
                            // Ожидать от клиента уведомления о завершении передачи файла.
                            cond_exec->wait(lock);
                            // Здесь - чтение файла, переданного в общую память.
                            // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                            // По окончанию чтения, известить процесс, отправивший файл, что файл был принят и прочитан.
                            cond_done->notify_one();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (interprocess_exception& ex)
            {
                . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
            }
        }
    }, token);
serverTask.wait();
```

Почему строка кода

```
scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mtx };
```

так себя ведёт? Почему, когда курсор пошаговой отладки стоит на ней и я нажимаю F10 для выполнения перехода к следующей строке отлаживаемого кода, то этот переход не выполняется? Что я делаю неправильно в своей программе? Пожалуйста, помогите. Буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В одном процессе мьютекс блокируется и начинается бесконечный цикл, и в другом. Код после `while` в обоих случаях недостижим. В клиенте разблокировки мьютекса вообще не может случится. А вот ожидание condition variable сделано неверно - как раз там-то и надо крутится в цикле проверяя условие ожидания.

Comment: Дело в том, что после срабатывания строки кода scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mutexPare.first }; на сервере, выполнение не доходит до следующей строки кода: while (1) - начало бесконечного цикла. В этом-то и проблема. На клиенте, в это время, мьютекс ещё не заблокирован, потому что там код scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mutexPare.first }; запускается по щелчку по кнопке.

Comment: @Prohor Ну значит он уже в заблокированном состоянии при старте процесса. Такое может случится если предыдущий процесс был завершен, пока мьютекс был заблокирован. Так или иначе, ничего не работает.

Comment: Эта ситуация происходит, когда я запускаю программу сразу после включения компьютера. Т.е., до этого мьютекс не использовался. Почему так происходит? Может использовать для создания общей памяти managed_windows_shared_memory, а не managed_shared_memory?

Comment: @Prohor Потому что мьютекс мог быть заблокирован когда-то раньше, а разделяемая память - это файл на диске. managed_windows_shared_memory может помочь за счет отсутствия персистентного состояния, однако код все равно не будет работать по указанным выше причинам.

Comment: На сервере после строки кода: std::pair<interprocess_mutex*, size_t> mutexPare = managed_shm.find<interprocess_mutex>("mtx"); использовал: mutexPare.first->internal_mutex().unlock(); Помогло. В отладке видно, что на сервере начал выполняться код, следующий за: scoped_lock<interprocess_mutex> lock{ *mutexPare.first }; Но ни в одном из примеров boost (что я посмотрел за эти дни) почему-то не используется вызов unlock() для мьютекса.

Comment: Поменял на сервере. 1) Перед созданием managed_shared_memory добавил: struct shm_remove
                    {
                        shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("GUID"); }
                        ~shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("GUID"); }
                    } remover;. 2) При создании managed_shared_memory заменил модификатор open_or_create на create_only. 3) Удалил код mutexPare.first->internal_mutex().unlock();. Проверил - сервер работает нормально. Помогло.

Comment: @Prohor это потому что там используется RAII и вызов unlock происходит в деструкторе lock.